# Laravel endless scrolling

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to build a endless-scrolling functionality in my Laravel app. When a user visits my Page I load the first 10 Items with PHP.

```
MyModal::skip(0)->take(10)->get()
```

For sure I could get the next Items with

```
MyModal::skip(10)->take(10)->get()
```

But the problem is, when there are new entrys added while I scroll to the bottom. How can I tell Laravel "give me the next 10 items starting from the item with the ID X"

I hope you understand my question.

Comment: have you tried pagination?

Comment: When requesting the next items you could also send the `first id` (so even if new items are added in the process) from the list and query items greater than that id using pagination...this is how I would approach this

Answer (score 0):

You could use an approach like this. You probably have a route that is inserted at the end of the view as an anchor link and calls the next 10 results, using AJAX.

So, the route should be something like this:

```
Route::get('/mymodal/{skip?}', 'MyModalController@nextItems');
```

This would call the Controller with the possibility to skip some items. And then the next skip value would be sent to the view with the results.

```
public function nextItems(Request $request, $skip = 0) {
    $results = MyModal::skip($skip)->take(10)->get();
    return view('mymodals.theview', [
            'results' => $results,
            'skip' => $skip + 10
    ]);
}
```

And then, in the view, you add the skip value to the anchor:

```
@foreach ($results as $r)
    (...)
@endforeach

<a href="{{action('MyModalController@nextItems', $skip)}}">Next page...</a>
```

Hope you get the idea. I've used the same idea in a project, but with the timestamp as parameter, and it works flawlessly.